# Running different version of Python gives a "not found" error

Tags: python, bash, shell, virtualenv, google-cloud-dataflow

I have an external application that comes as a standalone package with it's own python subset and dependencies. I intend to couple this package with my own python code and run it on Google Cloud Dataflow. I have the pipeline ready. I need help with running the shell script that gives error "not found"

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/python2.7: not found
```

I call the script from my python code using

```
Process =  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/Process'
subprocess.check_call([Process , str(filepath)])
```

The contents of Process are:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/Bashrc

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/python2.7 -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package_name>/Process.py  "$@"
```

I've tried placing the checks in my python code

```
if os.path.exists("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/Process"):
 logging.info("Process exists")
else:
  logging.info("Process does not exists")

if os.path.exists("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/python2.7"):
  logging.info("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/python2.7 exists")
else:
  logging.info("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/python2.7 does not exist")

if os.path.exists("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/Bashrc"):
    logging.info("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/Bashrc exists")
else:
    logging.info("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/Bashrc does not exist")
```

All of them affirm that the file exists. If I do a `<package>/bin/python2.7` on my system, it launches IDLE perfectly.

This problem is very related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775248/install-different-versions-of-python-packages-and-access-via-shell-command). I've also edited the PYTHONPATH, PATH and other environment variables to include `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/`

I expect the subset python binary to run and start executing Process.py with all the input parameters. What should I do?

Basically I want to pass the variable `filepath` to Process as an argument from a function.

Comment: Or the package was set to run in Python 3!

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/bin/python2.7 -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/<package>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package_name>/Process.py  "$@"` is how the standard installation starts the process. Therefore, I believe it's meant to use Python 2.7. Moreover I'm firing a shell command by saying `shell=True` therefore the interpreter should run as is.